# Google BigQuery installation

Tags: python, google-bigquery

Having tried to install bq command-line tool still with no success im running out of ideas.
I have tried to install it using easyinstall bigquery, also with the manually provided path e.g. easy_install http://code.google.com/p/google-bigquery-tools/downloads/list/bigquery-2.0.7.tar. As well as manually downloading the tar files running setup.py install.

During installation im prompted an error message: Download error on the **http://ipython/scipy.org/moin/PyReadline/Intro: timed out -- Some packages my not be found!**
So i manually installed pyreadline by extracting the pyreadline.py and its libs to my python installation., without any luck

A similar problem have been discussed [https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/bigquery-discuss/60X4NS8sgHk[1-25]](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/bigquery-discuss/60X4NS8sgHk%5B1-25%5D)

however i experience the same downloading issue for the ipython.scipy.org.

Any ideas on alternative installtions for these missing packages or what ever other problem it might be?

running bq:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Python27\Scripts\bq-script.py", line 5, in <module>
from pkg_resources import load_entry_point
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 2815, in <module>
working_set.require(__requires__)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 690, in require
needed = self.resolve(parse_requirements(requirements))
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\distribute-0.6.28-py2.7.egg\pkg_resources.py", line 588, in resolve
raise DistributionNotFound(req) pkg_resources.DistributionNotFound: pyreadline
```

Comment: seems that it is possible to download the required pyreadline from PyPi, atleast seems to have solved the issue with pyreadline. availible at http://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline

Comment: can you post this comment as an official answer below, and then click on "answered?"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that it is possible to download the required pyreadline from PyPi, atleast seems to have solved the issue with pyreadline. availible at pypi.python.org/pypi/pyreadline